# postgresql - how to align columns when selecting cyrillic text (utf-8)?

Tags: postgresql-9.1, psql

My database is utf-8. When selecting a text field from a table it looks like this:

```
postgres=#  select '>'||exp_type||'<', exp_id from t_exp_types where exp_id in (3,11,12,15);
+-----------------------------------------+--------+
|                ?column?                 | exp_id |
+-----------------------------------------+--------+
| >храна<                            |      3 |
| >почивка<                        |     11 |
| >превод<                          |     12 |
| >изравнителен превод< |     15 |
+-----------------------------------------+--------+
(4 rows)
```

How can I make the columns aligned properly? psql (PostgreSQL) 9.1.3

**solution:** my locale LC_ALL was set to 'C'. Changing to LC_ALL= fixed the problem

Comment: Use a current PostgreSQL?

Comment: just upgraded to psql (PostgreSQL) 9.3.4 -> still the same problem

Comment: Operating system and version, terminal, locale?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works fine here:

```
regress=> WITH t_exp_types(exp_id, exp_type) AS (VALUES (3, 'храна'), (11, 'почивка'), (12, 'превод'), (15, 'изравнителен превод'))
regress-> select '>'||exp_type||'<', exp_id from t_exp_types where exp_id in (3,11,12,15);
       ?column?        | exp_id 
-----------------------+--------
 >храна<               |      3
 >почивка<             |     11
 >превод<              |     12
 >изравнителен превод< |     15
(4 rows)
```

Fedora 19, Konsole 2.11.2 from KDE 4.11.2. My locale is:

```
$ locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

Odd symptoms, though; a simple `client_encoding` mismatch would mangle the characters, not just the whitespace.

Comment: Mine was LC_ALL=C. Changing it to LC_ALL=    did the job. Thank you.

Comment: Yeah, `LC_ALL=C` is dead wrong for unicode output. Still a very surprising and weird symptom, I'd expect hopelessly garbled text.