# Postgres psql not aligning columns in output of SELECT

Tags: postgresql, psql

Running psql in Linux and I seem to have switched off alignment in the output.
Below I would expect 'bar' to be listed under 'header_2'

```
postgres=# select 'foo' as header_1, 'bar'  as header_2; 
header_1¦header_2
foo¦bar
(1 row)
```

I've tried setting the field separater to tab with

```
postgres=# \f '\t'
Field separator is "    ".
postgres=# select 'foo' as header_1, 'bar'  as header_2; 
header_1        header_2
foo     bar
(1 row)
```

... but 'bar' is still not aligned under 'header_2'

Whenever I search the documentation it thinks I'm referring to delimiting csv files and things like that, rather than just screen output.

Comment: Are you using -A or --no-align as a psql argument?

Comment: It could also be the encoding of the output. You can check your LOCALE settings for that.

Comment: OK I'll check that. It's running inside a docker

Comment: Thank you! I shut the docker down and fired it back up and it's aligning everything correctly now.

Comment: @JSpratt would like to upvote you and accept answer but can't seem to. New to stack overflow. Thank you

Comment: No worries. Just a small tip. If it was the locale settings and you want to upvote an answer you can upvote Craig Ringer's answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22622017/postgresql-how-to-align-columns-when-selecting-cyrillic-text-utf-8 where I got the idea.

Comment: You can turn alignment off inside psql with `\a`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the -A or --no-align parameter when making a psql connection. By default the output mode is set to *aligned*. This way you can change it to non-aligned. At the same time, this parameter does the same job as "\pset format unaligned".